# In regards to Starcraft II, what is a "vod"?

Tags: terminology, starcraft-2

I've been reading some StarCraft II strategy forums, and I have not been able to figure out what is meant by "vod".  What does it mean?

Example usage here: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=140944

EDIT: A description of its etymology, if it's not apparent from its meaning, would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VOD is Video On Demand.
On this context, it means a video that is taken from the screen of an observer or from the players themselves (those are called FPVOD-First Person VOD). The video is taken by softwares like FRAPS, in most of the cases. They usually have audio commentary from "experts" in the game, but this is not required.

VODs are used usually when the replay is not available, i.e: in Korean professional league games.

Answer (score 0):

It's a video of a StarCraft match. Replay is how it would be said in modern parlance. But Vods might be a full-motion video, and it might have commentary.

Comment: "full-motion"?  As opposed to what?

Comment: @StrixVaria, A SC2 replay file doesn't store data about each frame, it just stores where the units are moving, and what they're attacking, etc, and the StarCraft 2 engine just plays the replay, and you can watch it as it's happening. A video file stores images for each frame (or deltas, depending on compressions) and can be played outside of the StarCraft client, like in windows media player, or quick time, and it can also have additional data like a shoutcaster describing what's happening or something, a video file can be uploaded to youtube. A replay only has what happened during the game.

Comment: Ah.  I was aware of the replay storage algorithm, just not that that was the distinction you were trying to make.

Comment: Err a replay is not a modern version of a VOD.

Answer (score -2):

VOD is a video that is recorded by the player them self or by a live viewer. Although it is recorded live VOD's do not need to be watched live as they are being recorded(common sense). VOD's also contain commentary or some voice on that explains what is going on or is just talking about the game itself. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hint: your answer is probably downvoted because it does not add anything to other answers given before.